# Trying to check if textboxes empty or not and alerting the user

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use Javascript to check if textboxes are empty or not and alerting which one is empty/invalid. Since I'm using Notepad++, I can't seem to find the problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#sButton").click(function(){
                if( $('#demo').html().length == 0){
                    alert("Name part is empty!");
                }
                if( $('#demo2').html().length == 0){
                    alert("Surname part is empty!");
                }
            }
        }
<body>

  <p>Name:</p><div id="demo"> <input type="text" name="fname"></div>
  <br><br>
  <p>Surname:</p><div id="demo2"><input type="text" name="lname"></div>
  <br><br>

  <div><input type="submit" value="Submit" id="sButton"></div>
```

Comment: The `.html()` doesn't select value of input. You should use `$("#demo input").val()` instead

Comment: 'Since I'm using Notepad++, I can't seem to find the problem'. Then stop using Notepad++!

Comment: try using vscode or sublime ,they can debug the issue when you are typing

Comment: Or use a JS lint plugin for Notepad++: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jslintnpp/

Answer (score 2):

`sButton` is a `class` not an `id` so use class selector,Hope this helps

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".sButton").click(function(){
                if(! $(".name").val().trim()){
                    alert("Name part is empty!");
                }
                else if( !  $(".lname").val().trim()){
                    alert("Surname part is empty!");
                }
                else
                alert("Form Submitted")
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Name:</p><div id="demo"> <input class="name" type="text" name="fname"></div>
  <br><br>
  <p>Surname:</p><div id="demo2"><input class="lname" type="text" name="lname"></div>
  <br><br>

  <div><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="sButton"></div>
```

Comment: This works snippet but when I try running it on NotePad++, the problem persists.

Comment: I can't see the error. I run it on NotePad++. Is there a way to see it?

Answer (score 0):

change **class** to **id**

```
<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" id="sButton"></div>
```

Comment: Didn't work. I was switching between class and id to try both, that's why it was like this. I will edit it right away.

Comment: or change ``$("#sButton")`` to ``$(".sButton")`` to make sure it's addressing a class, but then every button with the same class will trigger the event.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the id demo and demo2 to both inputs and the use the below code to check if the text area is empty or not

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".sButton").click(function(){
                if( $('#demo').val() == ""){
                    alert("Name part is empty!");
                } else if( $('#demo2').val() == ""){
                    alert("Surname part is empty!");
                } else {
                    alert("All fields are filled");
                }

            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Name:</p><div > <input id="demo" type="text" name="fname"></div>
<br><br>
<p>Surname:</p><div ><input id="demo2" type="text" name="lname"></div>
<br><br>
<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="sButton"></div>
```

Comment: if the user has 10 input field then then your code will show 10 alerts, Is this standard??

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this too

I've given the inputs a `input` class, and with `each` I loop through all the elements with this class.

With the this method, you can check if any of the inputs with the given class is empty.

If yes, then you add the class `.error`, which gives it a red border, to the one which is empty.

I solved the alert part by giving them a `placeholder` attribute, and if one is empty, the following code: `alert($(this).attr("placeholder")+" is empty!");` will alert it's placeholder+" is empty".

I would recommend this solution, because it can work with 10,20 or more inputs too, as long as you give them the `input` class. But I don't recommend doing it with alerts.

In this code, you'll know which one is empty, since it will have a red border.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".sButton").click(function(){
             $(".input").each(function(){
          if($(this).val()==""){
          $(this).addClass("error");
          alert($(this).attr("placeholder")+" is empty!");
    }
    else{
    $(this).removeClass("error");
    }
  });
               
            });
           
        });
```

```css
.error{
border:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Name:</p><div id="demo"> <input class="name input" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Name"></div>
  <br><br>
  <p>Surname:</p><div id="demo2"><input class="lname input" type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Surname"></div>
  <br><br>

  <div><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="sButton"></div>
```